# Struts2 2.3.16.1→2.3.28.1へVerUP後、jspの一部の<s:property>が実行されない

Tags: java, jsp, struts

お疲れ様です。nanazipと申します。
掲題の通り、Struts2を2.3.16.1から、最新版である2.3.28.1へバージョンアップしました。

すると、jspでs:propertyで取得している値の一部が取得できなくなりました。
具体的には、下記のようになります。

```
<s:iterator value="testList" var="rst" status="stts">
<s:set var="str" value="#rst.result"> 

<!-- 値の取得ができている  s property -->
<s:property value="%{example.util.StringUtil@toString(#str.test)}" />
<!-- 値の取得ができていないs property -->
<s:property value="%{example.util.StringUtil@toString(#str.gTest)}" />
```

値は一部置き換えて掲載しております。

2.3.16.1では両方とも値の取得ができていたので、OGNL脆弱性対策で何らかの対応が加わり、後者の gTest の呼び出しが無効になっているのではないかと推測しています。

また、値の取得ができていないs property、gTestのフィールド名、及びgetter,setterを下記のように修正したところ、値の取得ができました。
    gTest→grpTest
    getGTest()→getGrpTest()
    setGTest()→setGrpTest()

```
<s:property value="%{example.util.StringUtil@toString(#str.grpTest)}" />
```

現状、とりあえず応急処置はできたけど、原因がわからないという所です。
本事象を招いたバージョン、より少ない修正方法をご存知の方、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。
お手数をお掛けします。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

結論だけ書くと、JSP上で下記のように書けばいいと思います。

```
<s:property value="%{example.util.StringUtil@toString(#str.GTest)}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts2.3.24.1→2.3.28の段階で適用された、ognl3.0.6→3.0.11への更新が原因で発生する問題です。
対応については gertrud様の対応が一番簡単でしょうか。

Comment: 上記バージョンアップによる動作確認、対応後の動作も確認しました。